# how to move an inner html style tag to css correctly?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, web-application-design

i'm new to css and html,

would like to separete between the css and html part in order to write better code.

Writing a list component with a favorite/unfavorite option.
this is the body in my index.html

would like to move style="visibility:hidden" to the css file styles.css under same project. how can i acess this specific tag from styles.css ?

thank you!

```
<body>

<ul class="leftSidebarList mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--three-line">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
          <a class="likeUnlike" href="#">

          <i class="nonFavBtn" onclick="favOnclick(this)" class="material-icons">favorite_border</i>
          <i class="favBtn" onclick="favOnclick(this)" style="visibility:hidden" class="material-icons">favorite</i>

      </a>
    </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: tried to repharse the question so it would be clearer, hopes it's better now

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you can do to move style to css file. as you have two tags with same class 
1) you can add extra class to  this tag and add css style like 
.mdl-list__item-secondary-content .fav{visibility:hidden;}
2) you can use css selectors .mdl-list__item-secondary-content .likeUnlike i+i {visibility:hidden;}
if the css doesn't work you can use visibility:hidden !important;
reference 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Comment: i tried to do what you seggested in 1) by adding an extra class, and the css i added was : .mdl-list__item-secondary-content .favBtn{visibility:hidden;}     but i think i did it wrong since now i have two classed under the same tag, it doensn't recognice the material.io , not sure what to do..